# "You have an up to date CV and some published code for us to review" - what does it mean?

Tags: software-industry, recruitment, job-description

I am a Microsoft .NET developer have been looking for a job for last some months, and suddenly came across a particular company, where they are looking for **Senior/Lead** developer. I don't qualify for that post though, on that job application this particular line was mentioned.

**"You have an up to date CV and some published code for us to review"**

What does it mean actually? What does the company expect?

Comment: It's presumably listed under "requirements" or similar, in which case it would be equivalent to "We require that ... you have an up to date CV and some published code we can take a look at". If you're wondering specifically about what they might be referring to when they say "published code" (as in - published where?), or some other part, you might want to focus on that instead of just asking what the sentence means. At the moment it's more of an English language question than a workplace one.

Comment: @Dukeling [yes, it's under "Skills and Requirements | About you"](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/146938/full-stack-web-developer-thailand-bangkok-crazy-factory)

Answer (score 12):

What don't you understand? It seems self-explanatory to me...

They want to make sure that if you are applying for this position:

- Your CV/resume contains contains all recent work, including what you're working on right now (not two years ago)
- You have code they can look at, either on github.com (or similar), or you can provide them some code samples (that aren't the property of your employer or covered by an NDA.)

Providing sample code is necessary for the employer to judge your abilities; it's like a journalist providing writing samples.

Comment: Re the published code requirement: Job ads like this are a really good example of why it's a good idea for all devs to get involved in open source. I can go into an interview and demonstrate that I am a contributor to several of the products that I would be working with; that immediately puts me at a huge advantage because it shows that I'm familiar with those products at a deep level. Even if you are just filing bug reports or feature requests rather than writing code, that activity on Github can be used to demonstrate that you are engaged with the product and know it in depth.

Comment: On the opposite, you could perfectly have a total perfect demo project that took you so much time for your set of skills that in fact once in the jobs you're either too slow or don't produce the same quaility of code.

Answer (score 3):

It is understandable that you may not recognise what a "CV" is. If you're American (or learned American English), you will probably use the word "resumé" instead.

But "published code for review" seems fairly self explanatory: they want to see your public record (probably on Github) so that they can evaluate your abilities by looking at your actual code.

If you have a Github account, I suggest you provide them with your ID so that they can look you up and see what you've been doing. Likewise with Bitbucket or Gitlab or elsewhere. Also if you have contributed to any third-party open source projects you should give direct links to them as well.

Another source of public code that you could share could be blog posts where you've discussed coding techniques, or answers on StackOverflow where you've given a code solution to a problem. Either of these would also be a good way to showcase yourself to them.

If you don't have any code that you've published in pubic, then honestly, you may struggle to get the role; if they're asking to see your public code, then it implies that they place value in you having some public code or open source contributions, so you are already putting yourself at a disadvantage. You can (and should) still apply, and either provide them directly with some code samples that aren't public or provide a good explanation of why you can't do that. Make sure your CV/resume is as strong as you can make it, to compensate for the lack of code.

Comment: but they want .net code most OS projects are not MS based. Also they seem an amateur night operation with a sketchy grasp of employment law as your employer might well own all code that you produce

Comment: @Neuromancer - Maybe they're specifically looking for someone with open source experience in the .Net field. There are plenty of them around. I don't agree with your second sentence: The OP said that they asked for *published* code, so there's no evidence that they're trying to get private code written for an employer. You're right of course that one shouldn't share that kind of private code, but that's not what's being asked for as far as I can see.

Comment: most employment contracts assign all IP related to your job to them